# Looped append of values to list resulting in ValueError: too many values to unpack

Tags: python, list

Apologies if I'm making a rookie error here, I've only been coding a couple weeks. I am attempting to build a function that takes a series of data and builds a set of bootstrap replicates.

To do this, I believe I want to:

1. build a list of values selected at random from the initial data series
2. aggregate the values into a list of key, value pairs
3. create an empty list to collect these aggregates
4. loop through 1,2 some number of times appending the values of each aggregate (from step 2) into the list (from 3)

I can get 1 and 2 down, I think... My first block of code is the following:

```
test_list = ['ABBV', 'ABBV', 'ACV1', 'ACV1', 'ACV1', 'ACV1', 'ACV1', 'AMKR', 'AMKR', 'AMKR']
data = test_list

def bootstrap_replicate_vc(data):
    """Generate single bootstrap replicate of 1D data."""
    bs_sample = np.random.choice(data, len(data))
    bs_rep = collections.defaultdict(list)                              
    for value in bs_sample:                            
        if value not in bs_rep:               
            bs_rep[value] = 1                       
        else :                                  
            bs_rep[value] = bs_rep[value] + 1  
    return bs_rep
```

When I run this I get what I expect as a single bootstrapped replication of my categorical series, for example:

```
bs_rep1 = bootstrap_replicate_vc(data) #check 
print(bs_rep1)
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'ACV1': 6, 'ABBV': 1, 'AMKR': 3})
```

My desire is to then create a function to iterate on the prior function to build additional bootstrapped replicates and append the values to the appropriate keys. So, an additional iteration (now size 2) should look something like this:

```
bs_reps = bootstrap_reps_categorical(data, size=2) #check 
print(bs_rep1)
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'ACV1': [6, 5], 'ABBV': [1,3], 'AMKR': [3,2]})
```

What I wrote to get there was:

```
def generate_bs_reps_categorical(data, size=1):
# Initialize array of replicates: bs_replicates
bs_reps = collections.defaultdict(list)
# Generate replicates
for i in range(size):
    bs_rep = bootstrap_replicate_vc(data)
    for key, value in bs_rep:
        bs_reps[key].append(value)
return bs_reps
```

However, when I run this I get a Value Error.
*ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)*

I modeled this off of [the python documentation I saw when researching this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) but I'm definitely not getting the right result.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: From reading the link here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict, found that the return value is dict-like, so if it is works as dict you should call `for key, value in bs_rep.items()` in last snippet. Give it a try.

Comment: Awesome, thanks it was a rookie error. Didn't realize that was necessary.